# Is there an elegant way do collect and convert the type at the same time in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list of properties which can put to different categories. The value type differs. But different categories might have the same value type.

```
val data: List[(String, Any)] = List("first name" -> "rockie", 
                                     "last name" -> "yang",
                                     "address" -> "rather not reveal",
                                     "wanted age" -> 23)

val publicProps = Set("first name", "last name")
val privateProps = Set("address", "wanted age")

val filtered = data.filter(d => publicProps.contains(d._1))

// but the type of filtered is List[(String, Any)]

// I could do a map to convert the type to List[(String, String)]
filtered.map{case (name, value: String) => name -> value}

// If the number of publicProps is small
// I could do collect and convert at the same type
data.collect {
    case ("first name", value: String) =>
        ("first name", value)
    case ("last name", value: String) =>
        ("last name", value)
}
```

Is there an elegant way do collect and convert the type at the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you find elegant. And how sure you are that all values of a publicProp are Strings.

```
data.collect {
    case (key, value: String) if publicProps.contains(key) => (key, value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Since I am sure it's string, that's why I need convert the time at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
data.collect {
   case (k, v: String) if publicProps.contains(k) => (k, v)
}
```

Comment: you don't need "contains". `.. if publicProps(k)  => ...` would be even more "elegant" ;)

Comment: @Dima right, that would be shorter. I still find `contains` more readable :)